# How do I implement Jupiter's VersionedTransactions into Python?

Tags: python, versionedtransactions, sendtransactionerror, swap, jupiter

I've been having a bit of trouble while trying to implement Jupiter's V4 swap API into my program. Although I haven't had any issues retrieving the transaction, I haven't figured out how to execute the versioned transaction, which the `solana.py` library now supports. I've been trying to port the [code used](https://docs.jup.ag/integrating-jupiter-1/start-with-the-jupiter-api#7.-deserialize-and-sign-the-transaction) in Jupiter's documentation, but unfortunately haven't had any luck yet.

```
# Deserializes and sends the transaction from the swap information given
def send_transaction(swap_transaction, opts):

    # Using bytes(base64.b64decode(example)) equivalent of Buffer.from(example, 'base64')
    txn_buffer = bytes(base64.b64decode(swap_transaction))
    transaction = Transaction.deserialize(txn_buffer)
    transaction.sign(keypair)
    raw_transaction = transaction.serialize()

    result = client.send_raw_transaction(raw_transaction, opts=opts)
    txid = result.value
    print(colors.HEADER + timestamp.find_time() + f": Merx TxID: {txid}" + colors.ENDC)
    return(txid)
```

The only error I receive simply states `transaction error` without any further information.
I'm new to versioned transactions and haven't been able to find any useful documentation from Jupiter or the Python library. Is there a solution to this problem that I've been struggling to solve?

Comment: You'll need to use `solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.from_bytes`

Comment: @KevinH in what aspect? Sorry, but the docs don't give much at all on that function.

Comment: like this: `transaction = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(txn_buffer)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is solution for VersionedTransaction for Jupiter API

```
swap_instruction = swap_tx_response.json()["swapTransaction"]

raw_tx = solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(swap_instruction))

signature = keypair.sign_message(solders.message.to_bytes_versioned(raw_tx.message))

signed_tx = solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.populate(raw_tx.message, [signature])
encoded_tx = base64.b64encode(bytes(signed_tx)).decode('utf-8')

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
data = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "sendTransaction",
    "params": [
        encoded_tx,
        {
            "skipPreflight": True,
            "preflightCommitment": "finalized",
            "encoding": "base64",
            "maxRetries": None,
            "minContextSlot": None
        }
    ]
}
tx_response = httpx.post("rpc_url", headers=headers, json=data)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works just as expected. However, I found out that it isn't necessary to use `httpx.post()` as `client.send_raw_transaction()` works fine as well.

Comment: Yes, I just don't use solana library that's why I use httpx

Answer (score 0):

You can use even send_transaction()

```
    swap_instruction = r.json()["swapTransaction"]

    raw_tx = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(swap_instruction))

    signature = self.kp.sign_message(to_bytes_versioned(raw_tx.message))

    signed_tx = VersionedTransaction.populate(raw_tx.message, [signature])

    txid = self.client.send_transaction(
        signed_tx,
        opts=TxOpts(skip_confirmation=False, skip_preflight=True, max_retries=3),
    ).value

    print(txid)
```